# Test my custom created DNS?

Tags: networking, server, dns, customization, ruby

I used VPS Ubuntu 14.04 (x64) to install test environment for my Ruby on Rails development. And I succeed with installing and configuring.

Now I also configured DNS on that VPS server, everything looks okay, but my external domains (hostet by godaddy,bluehost) does not work even I set theirs DNS records to my new DNS.

I tested bind9 service and its looks it works well. All configuration I use here was work well on VSPDime server, now I am using servermania vps hosting.

This is my '/etc/bind/named.conf.options'  file content:

```
  options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-recursion { 23.229.38.20; 127.0.0.1; };
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no; # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
    };
    };
    logging {
    channel default {
    file "/var/log/named/named.log" versions 3 size 16m;
    };
    category default { default; };
    };
```

This is my '/etc/bind/named.conf.local' file content

```
zone "rubyonerails.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rubyonerails.com.db";
};
```

And this is '/etc/bind/zones/rubyonerails.com.db' file content.

```
$TTL 600
rubyonerails.com.      IN      SOA     ns1.rubyonerails.com. admin.rubyonerails.com. (
                                                        2006081401
                                                        28800
                                                        3600
                                                        604800
                                                        38400
)

rubyonerails.com.      IN      NS              ns1.rubyonerails.com.
rubyonerails.com.      IN      NS              ns2.rubyonerails.com.

rubyonerails.com.      IN      MX     10       mta.rubyonerails.com.

rubyonerails.com.       IN      A       23.229.38.20
*                       IN      A       23.229.38.20

ns1.rubyonerails.com.              IN      A       23.229.38.20
ns2.rubyonerails.com.              IN      A       23.229.38.20

www              IN      A       23.229.38.20
mta              IN      A       23.229.38.20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm after one day I think I fix the issue, and it was in spacing at '/etc/bind/zones/rubyonerails.com.db' file.

As I try lot of solutions I copied content from notepad to this file and all lines ware moved right by a TAB space.(I removed TAB space for all lines from left side)

Now I restarted bind9 and everything forks fine. My domain points to my custom DNS.

I am not sure is this 100% solution,  maybe guys from servermania hosting did something on their side, in meantime because I contact them also.  They said they did not do anything....

So, conclusion is "NO SPACES AND TABS IN DNS CONFIGURATION FILES"